# Open Source Angular Rest Client Libraries

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

HI i wish to know if there exists a library for angular js similar to retrofit in android, apache http client for java or RestTemplate for SpringBoot, .

I am able to successfully use https://angular.io/guide/http with rxjs but i have many api calls and i am looking if there exists a better solution which i am not aware of.

Some of my findings are:

- https://ngx-restangular.com/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-rest-client
- https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=ngx%20rest%20client [Parent reference]

It looks like they are either outdated or are not maintained recently.

Can someone please help me find a quick wrapper for this.

EDITED:

Added sample code which i am already using in project

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {Tweet} from '../api/models/response/Tweet';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';
import {AuthenticationService} from '../api/services/authentication.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TweetsService {
  tweetsUrl = '/tweets/timeline?page=0&size=25';
  sendTweetUrl = '/tweets/create';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient,
              private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {

  }

  getTweets(): Observable<Tweet[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Tweet[]>(environment.resourceApiUrl + this.tweetsUrl);
  }

  sendTweet(tweet: Tweet): Observable<Tweet> {
    return this.httpClient.post<Tweet>(environment.resourceApiUrl + this.sendTweetUrl, tweet);
  }
}
```

Comment: RxJS & HttpClient are already a wrapper to abstract the HTTP logic to you. Why don't you want to use it ? It's very powerful, rather lightweight, and fully integrated in Angular. Any counter arguments as to not to use it ?

Comment: Yes, i agree, but there is a lot of boiler plate code i need to write, i am not a regular angular coder hence, was looking something similar to https://square.github.io/retrofit/ which is eazy to configure and all endpoints remain at a place.

Comment: There's absolutely no boilerplate code to write to start using it. All you have to do is import it into your app module, and you can use it. But since you seem to be repelled by it, I would advise something like [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), which is less flexible, less powerful, but lighter and probably more suited to your needs (altough I really recommend you to stay on HttpClient).

Comment: I have added code which i am using for each service and injecting inside components. Please suggest if i should continue using the same!

Comment: I have added an answer to explain briefly. Also, if you ever use Axios, know that you will have the same amount of code (importing, requesting), so you really don't have much more code with Angular Http !

Comment: it sounds like you're asking for something like an autogenerated js client for your API, is that accurate?

Comment: nono, sorry dont take me wrong a rest client fo rest api in general! trichetriche's answer is near to what i am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Following my comments, I think this code is rather clean and short. If you find it too tidieous, you can factorize it along the line of

```
export class HttpService {
  constructor(...) {...}

  get<T>(url) {
    return this.http.get<T>(environment.apiURL + url);
  }
}
```

That would then reduce your "boilerplate code". But I definitely recommend going like you did, as it clearly separates the logic of each service (respsecting the [LIFT part of the style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#application-structure-and-ngmodules)), which is a very good practice !

Comment: I am looking something similar to this a wrapper!